# Why is LO_INC_WDRAW_ORIG_YR2_RT greater than LO_INC_WDRAW_ORIG_YR4_RT?

Tags: collegescorecard

The way I understand it, LO_INC_WDRAW_ORIG_YR2_RT is the number of low-income students that withdrew from the college within 2 years. There is also a variable for 3 years, 4, 6, and 8 years. I am confused because the maximum value goes down for larger years (in R, I have filtered "PrivacySuppressed" and "NULL" entries then arranged them in descending order by the LO_INC_WDRAW_ORIG_YR#_RT variables where # is 2, 3, 4, 6 or 8).

```
colleges %>% 
    select(INSTNM, LO_INC_WDRAW_ORIG_YR6_RT) %>% 
    filter(!(LO_INC_WDRAW_ORIG_YR6_RT == "PrivacySuppressed"), 
                 !(LO_INC_WDRAW_ORIG_YR6_RT == "NULL"),
                 !(is.na(LO_INC_WDRAW_ORIG_YR6_RT)), 
                 !(is.null(LO_INC_WDRAW_ORIG_YR6_RT))) %>% 
    arrange(desc(LO_INC_WDRAW_ORIG_YR6_RT))
```

Shouldn't the number of students that withdrew within 2 years be counted into the total for 3 years, and those be counted into the total for 4, etc, meaning the maximum value should go up rather than down?